# How save a json file in python from api response when the class is a list and object is not serializable

Tags: python, json

I have tried to find the answer but I could not find it

I am looking for the way to save in my computer a json file from python.

I call the API

```
configuration = api.Configuration()
configuration.api_key['X-XXXX-Application-ID'] = 'xxxxxxx'
configuration.api_key['X-XXX-Application-Key'] = 'xxxxxxxx1'

## List our parameters as search operators
opts= {
    'title': 'Deutsche Bank',
    'body': 'fraud',
    'language': ['en'],
    'published_at_start': 'NOW-7DAYS',
    'published_at_end': 'NOW',
    'per_page': 1,
    'sort_by': 'relevance'
}

try:
    ## Make a call to the Stories endpoint for stories that meet the criteria of the search operators
    api_response = api_instance.list_stories(**opts)
    ## Print the returned story
    pp(api_response.stories)
except ApiException as e:
    print('Exception when calling DefaultApi->list_stories: %s\n' % e)
```

I got the response like this

```
[{'author': {'avatar_url': None, 'id': 1688440, 'name': 'Pranav Nair'},
 'body': 'The law firm will investigate whether the bank or its officials have '
         'engaged in securities fraud or unlawful business practices. '
         'Industries: Bank Referenced Companies: Deutsche Bank',
 'categories': [{'confident': False,
                 'id': 'IAB11-5',
                 'level': 2,
                 'links': {'_self': 'https://,
                           'parent': 'https://'},
                 'score': 0.39,
                 'taxonomy': 'iab-qag'},
                {'confident': False,
                 'id': 'IAB3-12',
                 'level': 2,
                 'links': {'_self': 'https://api/v1/classify/taxonomy/iab-qag/IAB3-12',
                 'score': 0.16,
                 'taxonomy': 'iab-qag'},
 'clusters': [],
 'entities': {'body': [{'indices': [[168, 180]],
                        'links': {'dbpedia': 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Deutsche_Bank'},
                        'score': 1.0,
                        'text': 'Deutsche Bank',
                        'types': ['Bank',
                                  'Organisation',
                                  'Company',
                                  'Banking',
                                  'Agent']},
                       {'indices': [[80, 95]],
                        'links': {'dbpedia': 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Securities_fraud'},
                        'score': 1.0,
                        'text': 'securities fraud',
                        'types': ['Practice', 'Company']},
 'hashtags': ['#DeutscheBank', '#Bank', '#SecuritiesFraud'],
 'id': 3004661328,
 'keywords': ['Deutsche',
              'behalf',
              'Bank',
              'firm',
              'investors',
              'Deutsche Bank',
              'bank',
              'fraud',
              'unlawful'],
 'language': 'en',
 'links': {'canonical': None,
           'coverages': '/coverages?story_id=3004661328',
           'permalink': 'https://www.snl.com/interactivex/article.aspx?KPLT=7&id=58657069',
           'related_stories': '/related_stories?story_id=3004661328'},
 'media': [],
 'paragraphs_count': 1,
 'published_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 19, 16, 8, 5, tzinfo=tzutc()),
 'sentences_count': 2,
 'sentiment': {'body': {'polarity': 'positive', 'score': 0.599704},
               'title': {'polarity': 'neutral', 'score': 0.841333}},
 'social_shares_count': {'facebook': [],
                         'google_plus': [],

 'source': {'description': None,
            'domain': 'snl.com',
            'home_page_url': 'http://www.snl.com/',
            'id': 8256,
            'links_in_count': None,
            'locations': [{'city': 'Charlottesville',
                           'country': 'US',
                           'state': 'Virginia'}],
            'logo_url': None,
            'name': 'SNL Financial',
            'scopes': [{'city': None,
                        'country': 'US',
                        'level': 'national',
                        'state': None},
                       {'city': None,
                        'country': None,
                        'level': 'international',
                        'state': None}],
            'title': None},
 'summary': {'sentences': ['The law firm will investigate whether the bank or '
                           'its officials have engaged in securities fraud or '
                           'unlawful business practices.',
                           'Industries: Bank Referenced Companies: Deutsche '
                           'Bank']},
 'title': "Law firm to investigate Deutsche Bank's US ops on behalf of "
          'investors',
 'translations': {'en': None},
 'words_count': 26}]
```

In the documentation says "Stories you retrieve from the API are returned as JSON objects by default. These JSON story objects contain 22 top-level fields, whereas a full story object will contain 95 unique data points"​

The class is a list. When I have tried to save json file I have the error "TypeError: Object of type Story is not JSON serializable".

How I can save a json file in my computer?

Answer (score 0):

The response you got is not json, json uses double quotes, but here its single quotes. Copy paste your response in the following link to see the issues
 http://json.parser.online.fr/.

If you change it like
[{"author": {"avatar_url": None, "id": 1688440, "name": "Pranav Nair"},
 "body": "......

It will work,  You can use python json module to do it

```
import json
json.loads(the_dict_got_from_response).
```

But it should be the duty of the API provider to, To make it working you can json load the result you got.